# How to add complex types to a specific function

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to add types to this function

```
function getNewObjectFromKeys(source, keys) {
        return keys.reduce((acum, value) => {
            if(typeof source[value] !== 'undefined') {
                return {
                    ...acum,
                    [value]: source[value] 
                }
            }
            return acum;
        }, {});
    }
```

This function only returns a new object from argument `source` with specified keys from argument `keys`.

I was trying something like this

```
function getObjectWithKeys<K extends object, T extends keyof K>(source: K, keys: T[]): Pick<K, typeof keys[number]> {
    return keys.reduce((acum, value) => {
        if(typeof source[value] !== 'undefined') {
                return {
                    ...acum,
                    [value]: source[value] 
                }
            }
            return acum;
    }, {}) as Pick<K, typeof keys[number]>;
}
```

But that `as Pick<K, typeof keys[number]>` is not convincing me, could this typing strategy be improved ?

I couldn't accomplish this passing a type as generic param on `reduce` method. Any help ? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`typeof keys[number]` is exactly equivalent to your `T` type, so you can replace it with:

```
as Pick<K, T>;
```

But `Object.fromEntries` might look nicer - `reduce` is pretty verbose, ugly when the accumulator is an object in TypeScript, and arguably not appropriate for this sort of situation [even in JavaScript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaGjS7-qWzg).

```
function getObjectWithKeys<K extends object, T extends keyof K>(source: K, keys: T[]) {
    return Object.fromEntries(
        keys.map(
            key => [key, source[key]]
        )
    ) as Pick<K, T>;
}

const result = getObjectWithKeys({ foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar' }, ['foo'])
```

results in `result` being typed as

```
const result: Pick<{
    foo: string;
    bar: string;
}, "foo">
```

To also filter out undefineds, you can `.filter` after mapping:

```
        keys.map(
            key => [key, source[key]]
        )
        .filter(
            [, value] => value !== undefined
        )
```

Comment: This looks good except that you forgot to include the filter for undefined values.

Comment: The `T extends keyof K` guarantees that the keys are in the object. If they aren't, TS won't permit the `getObjectWithKeys` call.

Comment: If K has some optional fields, those could be omitted in the source but included in the the keys since they are still keys of the source’s type, right?

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance for the answer, and do you know if there is a possibility to add a correct returning type to this function removing that  `as Pick<K, T>` ? Because with the operator `as` we are telling to compiler something like "trust me, I know what I’m doing." and I don't know if there is a "way" to get this correct return type in a more automated way without using the operator `as`, maybe this case is out from typescript compiler scope and the only solution is use the operator `as`. Thanks